# 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, concat

A client reported that they were running on SQL Server 2012, and we delivered some test queries for testing prior to a final delivery, however:

> 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

I understand that `CONCAT()` is a new built-in function introduced in SQL Server 2012, which is all fine and well, however I have been asked to roll back my change to make this 2008R2 compatible under the guise of "the user executing the query may not have Transact-SQL permissions to execute." So I am just proving my point that the client most likely has a different version of SQL Server installed in DEV than they do in PROD.

I can't find any information about specifically denying `SELECT/EXECUTE` permissions for built-in scalar valued functions, but is it possible, and if so does the user still receive the same error text?

Comment: If concat is not working then try this one `SELECT (c.FirstName+','+c.LastName) AS FULLNAME FROM graduatejob c;`

Comment: CONCAT supports decimal type concat(ID + '_' + OtherID), ID can be int type.

Comment: In older versions, use this instead: `DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(200) = 'Shrink file completed. Target Size: ' + @TargetSize + ' MB. Timestamp: ' + CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`CONCAT` was introduced in SQL Server 2012; there is no way to make it work in SQL Server 2008 R2. From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx):

> [image]

There's also no way to make it fail in 2012+, even with compatibility level. So have your people check `SELECT @@VERSION;` on both servers; you'll find that where `CONCAT` fails it is < 11. In order to make your code compatible with earlier versions, you'll need to use the standard string concatenation operator (`+`). I don't know how you would do this with a scalar function, unless you always used the *exact* same number of input strings **and** you change your code to use `dbo.CONCAT()` instead of `CONCAT()` (there will be scenarios where it matters, plus if your function does anything the native doesn't do, you want consistent behavior if/when you upgrade). So I wouldn't recommend that approach. You may also need to add `NULL` handling and other minor changes (impossible to tell you how to change your existing script exactly, if we can't see it).

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. The code is trivial to change, as CONCAT() is just used to join some strings together before a SP_ExecuteSQL dynamic SQL call. 

I really just wanted to confirm that there was NO way to deny access to using CONCAT() in SQL Server 2012

Comment: @beeks I don't know of any way to deny users the ability to use `CONCAT()`, no. I don't quite follow what bearing that has on what you need to do to make the code work on 2008 R2, though. You need to *remove* `CONCAT()`, not add it.

Comment: yes, I understand how to make the code compatible with 2008 R2, that is trivial. Thanks for confirming that one cannot `DENY` access to this function.

Comment: Just to note when changing the concat to the + you'll need to ensure values being concatenated are strings to begin with, if you have any numerical fields it will try to add them (and fail because a string is not an int) so if there is a numeric field (type) make sure you convert / cast it to a string first

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ODBC CONCAT function like this:

```sql
SELECT {fn CONCAT('foo ', 'test') }
```

The problem with this is that this function only allows you two parameters at a time. So unless you want to use more than two like this:

```sql
SELECT {fn CONCAT('foo ', {fn CONCAT('test ', 'buddy')}) }
```

You might as well just use the '+' operator.